# Sitecore 8.2 PaaS (Azure) save xml read-able by all instances

Tags: sitecore

We have a Sitecore 8.2 update4 installation up and running as PaaS with 4 CD (web) instances. Due to emergency circumstances the responsible Sitecore developer is currently not available and therefore i'm supposed to find a solution for the problem at hand over this weekend and I hope you might be able to help. Note: I'm not a certified Sitecore developer but a quite experienced C# dev.

Problem:
There is an API called (in code) via http which returns an XML document (very small - just 2 nodes in it). It has been noticed that this is actually being done-/executed for each client who surfs this specific page. Of course this is super bad and also slows the page down (TTFB). So i actually moved the polling to this API to the backend via a scheduled task in Sitecore which works already perfect. 
However in my ignorance (I basically have almost no clue about developing against Sitecore) I wanted to store the returning xml document from the API to the local filesystem. This of course will not work when I want to read the XML again in a multi-instance environment.

So in summary I look for a way to store,read and update this xml document so it can be read by all 4 (or more) instances.

I found the following example: [Adding a file to the Sitecore Media Library programatically](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/adding-a-file-to-the-sitecore-media-library-programatically/)

But of course i'm very uncertain if it makes sense to store it in the MediaLibrary. By reading some older "Content API Cookbook" of SiteCore (remember i do not have access to the dev network of SiteCore) also the "Sitecore.Data.Fields.FileField" seems to be a solution. However, i do not want the field to be visible to ContentEditor's to avoid them modifying it.

Please understand i do not have super much time to learn everything about SiteCore and it is actually not my job to do so, but i offered my help. So a simple solution with a small example (as i could not really find a fitting example online) would be extremly helpful and highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid having to learn Sitecore and still improve the performance of your page without needing to massively rework the initial implementation, you could look into application memory caching of the response. This also avoids having to manage a file across instances.

By using the application cache, you can ensure that that instance only makes the call the first time it is requested, and then you can release the cache after a period of time to allow another call.

Typically, you would then invoke a method which would check if the cache was empty, and if the cache was empty it would fill it with the value from your API. Set the expiry based on how often you want to poll.

```
public void AddItemToCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    if (Cache["MyKey"] == null)
      Cache.Add("MyKey", "SomeXml", null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, onRemove);
}
```

See the documentation for it on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.caching.cache.add?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thank you Jay S for the reply. Since there was quite some time pressure i ended up anyway learning through the weekend how to code for Sitecore. My assumption was already correct that the MediaLibrary was a good place for managing the issue at hand. However, your solution is also quite interesting and probably would have worked too. Therefore, once again thank you!